# Remove UTC date from Highcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, utc

I have been facing this problem in Highcharts for a while now

The tooltip :

[image]

At the top, the date hour is in UTC format, I want it to be in the same format the data is (or local time zone and it shouldn't change to UTC etc, remove the "T & Z" from the date also!)

My snippets of code that concern tooltip are as follows :

```
dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                second : '%H:%M',
                minute : '%H:%M',
                hour : '%H:%M',
                day : '%e. %b %a',
                week : '%e',
                month : '%b',
                year : '%e'
                 },
            labels : {
                formatter: function(){ 
                  var daystr = Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b %a', this.value);
                  var first = daystr.substring (0,daystr.length - 1);
                  return first;                                                                                                                 //return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b,', this.value);
                }
```

And :

```
tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
         },
```

Also, the day coming on the x-axis is 2 days +/- , I tried removing the UTC format by setting useUTC to false, even that did not work.

I need to know how to get datehour in non-UTC format for the tooltip.

All approaches/suggestions are most welcome.

UPDATE :

Ok, somehow I am not able to remove the UTC from any of my tabs.
But it has somehow already removed from one tab. I have no idea how!

I used this at the end of my highcharts which is not working :

```
   ,setOptions : ({
            global : {
                            useUTC : false
            }
            })
```

However, where exactly do I use the following as mentioned on the site ( This is not working )

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

I really don't understand what is happening here. The first one should work technically.
Can you tell me exactly where to add these snippets, my huge code of highcharts starts as :

```
$j(function () {


            $j('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType:'xy'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Trend Graph'
            },     << And so on ....... >>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to indeed set [`useUTC`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) to false and then use [`timezoneOffset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.timezoneOffset) to be the same as timezone used in data.

`useUTC` didn't work? How did you set this? Make sure the same way as in demos.

Comment: check updated answer, tried a couple of methods, not working!

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle with some static data, I will check this.

Comment: It's not clear from the docs but you must have *both* `useUTC=false` and `timezoneOffset=whatever` to ensure everything shows in the chosen offset. @PawełFus The example for timzoneOffset in the docs doesn't include the useUTC property, which is confusing, just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

In your tooltip you should add xDateFormat for date format

```
tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        shared: true,
        valueDecimals: 2
    }
```

If you want to have date with time you need to add like this

```
tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        shared: true,
        valueDecimals: 2
    }
```

then remove dateTimeLabelFormats.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that useUTC should be set before creating your charts, otherwise it won't pick up the settings if you apply after.